# In the Poedit wrong line

Tags: wordpress, poedit

I have this line in my php file `<strong>%1$s</strong> has been successfully subscribed to %2$s` BUT in the Poedit it looks like that `<strong>%s</strong> has been successfully subscribed to %s` AND the line on the website stay untranslated. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the [GNU gettext manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html) to understand the concept of updating PO files from source code. Then use the combination of `xgettext` and `msgmerge` to update your PO file (which is clearly out of date) from the current sources. Or use Poedit’s update-from-sources functionality.

Comment: Thanks! I still learn your suggested material but the "Poedit’s update-from-sources" option didn't work, several lines missed altogether.

Comment: You know, “didn’t work” isn’t much detailed… You probably didn’t mark the strings as translatable or something. Gettext’s documentation on the use of `xgettext` (which is what Poedit uses under the hood) explains how to setup the sources.